# Wordpress and Linux server performance

Tags: linux, memory, performance, php, wordpress

I have a multisite wordpress instance running with 3.8 GB of RAM and 2.6 GHZ of Intel processor.

I am facing issue of site performance when more than 50 users get connected to the site. Site becomes unresponsive and gradually not accessible to users beyond this count of 50+ users. We get error as site is unreachable.

In normal day when there are around 20+ users the memory consumption of server is around 85% i.e. around 2 GB. with cache (SWAP) of around 1 GB.

So my question is, what should be done in order to have more users get connected to the site. We are expecting around 3000+ users on our event day.

Questions?

1) Does increasing the memory on server from 3.8 GB to higher value, help?

2) what changes has to be done in Wordpress application in order to boost performance on memory consumption and usage?

3) How ares php memory and server memory related?

Comment: Are you using apache? If so, I would take a look to the MaxClients parameter of the mpm_prefork module (if installed) and configuring it accordingly to your server memory.

Comment: Is that 1GB swap used or 1GB swap available?

Comment: yes we are using apache server 2.2.15. MaxClients 256;  ServerLimit 256. Do we need to change this? how will it affect the memory?

Comment: @EugenRieck: 1 GB is used during peak used in normal load our of 4 GB. it goes to 3GB plus in peak load.

Comment: 3000 simultaneous users or daily?  If your talking about 3000 simultaneous Your going to need 3-4x the amount of memory you currently have and your CPU isn't enough for this task

Answer (score 0):

Things to do:

1) Upgrade memory. You need it. No realistic servers run over 4gb RAM

2) Upgrade CPU: What's 2.6ghz? A Core 2 Duo?

3) Switch to nginx (Just my opinion)

4) If you are going to have 3000+ simultaneous users, you can look into a load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all disable swap. You are trashing disk, in essence exchanging it against nothing.

Next either configure realistic connection counts or upgrade RAM - wordpress ist notoriously memory-hungry.

Finally: If you can replace Apache with nginx and either php-fm or hhvm, you can get way better.